# Convert word document in PDF,e pub,by using third party dll in Sharepoint designer workflow 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to convert word document to PDF,  EPub, by using third party (.dll).

In SharePoint designer workflow in 2013.

So that I have question, Can we Install third party (.dll) in SharePoint workflow Designer for conversion?

Means I have created one simple application conversion of word to e Pub, PDF, Image by using (Spire.doc dll) in Visual Studio.

So this same conversion I want to work in SharePoint designer workflows?

So anybody has any solution then please provide me.

Thanks,

Samadhan

Answer (score 0):

Word to PDF conversion is available if you use **Nintex** workflows but not in OOTB designer  workflow.
If you are trying to do this in SharePoint 2013 on premise , it can be done if you can create a custom workflow action activity and deploy it . In the custom workflow activity you can leverage some of the solution you already have and do the word to PDF conversion.